# How to get playlist title with yt-dlp?

Tags: linux, bash, youtube, playlists, yt-dlp

I want to get the playlist title of a youtube playlist and store it in a variable in a bash script.

I have already tried these things:

- `-e` flag but it lists only the video titles
- `-o` flag and `--get-filename` but again the same
- the best try was to run yt-dlp and grep the first download line that contains the playlist name, but that seems too much for a basic job

Also note that I don't want to use:
`yt-dlp -o "%(playlist_title)s"`
because I want the name of the playlist only.

Is it possible to get the playlist title with yt-dlp? or I have to use a workaround like Pafy?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You need to simply use `--print` (or `-O`) instead of `-o`:

```
yt-dlp [the rest of your command] --skip-download --print playlist_title
```

See [documentation](https://github.com/yt-dlp/yt-dlp#verbosity-and-simulation-options):

> -O, --print [WHEN:]TEMPLATE     Field name or output template to print to screen, optionally prefixed with when to print it, separated by a ":".

`--skip-download` also prevents the download and you might want to add `--no-warnings` to output only the playlist title.

A full example with a playlist that outputs only one playlist title (for 1st video - `-I 1:1`):

```
yt-dlp https://youtube.com/playlist?list=PLpeFO20OwBF7iEECy0biLfP34s0j-8wzk -I 1:1 --skip-download --no-warning --print playlist_title
```

Comment: Using `-I 1:1` will fail when the first video in the playlist is unavailable.

Comment: Not too sure there's any good solution for that except cleaning your playlists. Perhaps a  script checking for command success and looping numbers until valid one is found.

Comment: You can find it in the JSON response, see my answer.

Comment: For the ones searching for the title of each video/item, `yt-dlp --skip-download --print title URL`

Answer (score 2):

The proper way of doing this (which will not fail if the first video in the playlist is unavailable), is by reading the `title` property from the JSON response, which can be acquired by using `--dump-single-json` (shorthand `-J`) together with `--flat-playlist`.

To then parse the JSON data and get the title, you can use [`jq`](https://jqlang.github.io/jq/):

```sh
playlist_title=$(yt-dlp "https://youtube.com/playlist?list=$playlist_id" \
                        --flat-playlist                                  \
                        --dump-single-json                               \
                | jq -r .title)
```